# Assistance working out time complexity of functions calling on other functions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am very new to computer science doing a course looking at basic concepts with Python. Currently I am looking at graphs and their implementations. I have realised that my understanding of time complexity isn't up to scratch, could anyone explain to me the following:-

```
for a in O(N)function()
    // do something O(1)
```

My understanding is that when I call a 'for' loop I am creating an O(n) complexity. But what happens when, by calling my 'for' loop I need to call another function - in this case with O(n)? Is this similar to calling a nested loop? so O(n^2)?

Therefore if I was to then on the indent replace '//do something' with another ''for a in O(N)function'' I am then creating a O(n^4) function?

Thank-you for taking time to look at my query

Comment: Yes, calling a function inside your loop that is O(n) make your algorithm complexity O(n^2), because for each element in your loop, you do a processing that requires O(n), so n * O(n) is O(n²).

Comment: `for a in O(N)function()`: means that you are basically iterating on values of a range/list returned by O(N) fn. The function is not called n times. @ReynaudF

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your quick responses! So I read that as, if I were to call my O(n) function within the for loop it would be O(n^2). However because I called it within the line of the for loop it is still O(N) because really I am iterating over the product of the function, such as a list. Thanks both of you

Comment: To make it simple, the total `big-O` complexity would be `n` times the `big-O`complexity of what you call in a `for a in O(n) function` loop.
If you call some `O(x)` function in the loop, the total complexity will be `O(x.n)`. You can then replace `x` with what you want.